# sklearn ColumnTransformer based preprocessor outputs different columns on Train and Test dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I was trying to learn how to use Pipelines and ColumnTransformer to effectively preprocess data before Regression.
Here's my attempt:

```
  def preprocess_data(X):
    cat_var = X.select_dtypes(['bool','object']).columns
    num_var = X.select_dtypes(['int64','float64']).columns

    steps = [('c', Pipeline(steps=[('s',SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
                                   ('oe',OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))]), cat_var),
             ('n', SimpleImputer(strategy='median'), num_var)]

    transformer = ColumnTransformer(transformers=steps, remainder='passthrough')


    X = transformer.fit_transform(X=X)

    return X
```

The problem is that when I transform the train and test datasets, it selects different number(Fewer) of columns for the test dataset. Which means that the model I trained would not work on the test data.

I have revised the code well and there is no data leak or related issues

What might be the reason for this ? Is there a fault in my logic ?

I am using the following [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data)

Thanks!

Solution:
Return the transformer as well as the preprocessed data.

```
   return X, transformer
```

Then use the transformer obeject to transform test data before predictions

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use this function for training and test set because you then would fit_transform twice. You need to fit the transformer with the training data but only transform for the test data. I recommend to use a sklearn pipeline for this, which does this process automatically, for example like this:

```
pipeline = Pipeline(
[
    ('preprocessing', preprocessor),
    ('clf', MLalgorithm())
]
```

)

Comment: Taken from here: https://moritzkoerber.github.io/python/tutorial/2019/10/11/blogpost/

Answer (score 0):

If one of the categorical columns in test does not have a category in train, you will end up with less columns. Below you can see the number of categorical levels for each variable you transform with onehot:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

train = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

COL = x.select_dtypes(['bool','object']).columns
pd.DataFrame({'var':COL,
              'n_train':[len(train[i].unique()) for i in COL],
              'n_test':[len(test[i].unique()) for i in COL]})


    var n_train n_test
0   MSZoning    5   6
1   Street  2   2
2   Alley   3   3
3   LotShape    4   4
4   LandContour 4   4
5   Utilities   2   2
6   LotConfig   5   5
7   LandSlope   3   3
8   Neighborhood    25  25
9   Condition1  9   9
10  Condition2  8   5
11  BldgType    5   5
12  HouseStyle  8   7
13  RoofStyle   6   6
14  RoofMatl    8   4
15  Exterior1st 15  14
16  Exterior2nd 16  16
17  MasVnrType  5   5
18  ExterQual   4   4
19  ExterCond   5   5
20  Foundation  6   6
21  BsmtQual    5   5
22  BsmtCond    5   5
23  BsmtExposure    5   5
24  BsmtFinType1    7   7
25  BsmtFinType2    7   7
26  Heating 6   4
27  HeatingQC   5   5
28  CentralAir  2   2
29  Electrical  6   4
30  KitchenQual 4   5
31  Functional  7   8
32  FireplaceQu 6   6
33  GarageType  7   7
34  GarageFinish    4   4
35  GarageQual  6   5
36  GarageCond  6   6
37  PavedDrive  3   3
38  PoolQC  4   3
39  Fence   5   5
40  MiscFeature 5   4
41  SaleType    9   10
42  SaleCondition   6   6
```

You need to make the test set variables categorical with the same defined categories, see [the examples here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Categorical.html)

Comment: That does not apply here since OP specified `handle_unknown='ignore'` in the pipeline which makes the transformer ignore categories that do appear in the test set but not in the training set.

Comment: if you process train and test separately ignore or not doesn't matter. try running the code @00schneider

Comment: @00schneider StupidWolf , both of your answers are correct. I had to reuse the transformer object which was fit to train data to transform my test data. I will make the updates to my question.

Comment: If you think an answer did answer your question, then you could consider to mark this answer as an accepted answer.